# Solr: Run TF-IDF on Articles and Get the Filtered Content back

Tags: solr, tf-idf

Goal: I have millions of articles and I want to remove general words (TF-IDF value less than a threshold) and get the articles back.

Solr has [Function Queries](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/function-queries.html) such as TF and IDF, but I have to query for each single term (word). If each article has around 300 words, then there will be 300 millions quires. It is too expensive.

*Static files such as `stopwords.txt` won't work for some complicated reasons.*

Is there a way let Solr gives the filtered content back to me? I was thinking adding a new `<fieldType>` in `schema.xml`, but I don't know which `<filter>` should I put in `<analyzer>`.

E.G., If `is`, `an`, `company`'s TF-IDF value are below the threshold, then

```
Original content: "Apple Inc. is an American multinational technology company."
Filtered content: "Apple Inc. American multinational technology"
```

Comment: Is, an,of,the,for are the stopward and can be applied to the field type. This can be removed at the time of indexing and query. If you want beyond this...then you can use the model provided by Wikipedia...if you know python you can try the nltk lib and do more filtering

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti  as I mentioned in the question, stopwords is only a subset. The nltk lib or pre-trained nlp models won't meet my requirement. I need precise TF-IDF values on a particular set.

Comment: I'm guessing you could hack the MoreLikeThis component to support something like that, since it already supports tf/df min/max cutoffs for which terms to use when generating its query against the index. The parameter `mlt.interestingTerms=list` might just do what you're looking for. If not, you could hack the component to return the terms instead of running the query, the response should effectively be what you're looking for.